# Adding custom content in actionSheetController

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-vue

Is there a way to use custom content instead of button list in `ionic.actionSheetController`? An example of this is in `ionic.modalController` I can use a custom `component` for the modal's content.

**ionic.modalController** example

```
import { ProductDetails } from "./../components";

...

return this.$ionic.modalController
  .create({
    component: ProductDetails,
    componentProps: {
      propsData: {
        data: item,
      }
    }
  })
  .then(m => m.present());
```

**ionic.actionSheetController** attempt

```
import { ProductDetails } from "./../components";

...

return this.$ionic.actionSheetController
  .create({
    header: item.title,
    subHeader: item.subTitle,
    component: ProductDetails,
    buttons: [
      {
        text: "Cancel",
        icon: "close",
        role: "cancel"
      }
    ]
  })
  .then(a => a.present());
```

Below is an image of what I want to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Action Sheet](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/action-sheet) Ionic component only accepts buttons, in contrast to the [Popover](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover) and [Modal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal) components that each accept a custom component.

Your best bet at approximating the kind of behavior you desire might be to use the [Popover](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover) component, adding a custom `enterAnimation` and `leaveAnimation` and setting the [width properties](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover#css-custom-properties) that Ionic have made available.

In the past (pre Ionic 4), one could grab the DOM elements and alter at will but with the new underlying web components, this is not possible. To get even more custom behavior, you would need to look to [StencilJS](https://stenciljs.com/) or similar to create a new component. This is a maintainability risk and is probably not necessary given the vast array of functionality built into Ionic.

Comment: Great workaround. Thanks... I went with Modal instead because it already has the right animation by default then I set `ion-modal { padding-top: 80%; }`

Comment: @SimoD'loMafuxwana `ion-modal { padding-top: 80%; }` does not work when the device is in landscape mode, is there any other solution for this?